# React function is called twice instead of once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm creating Sudoku game app using React. Currently I'm creating the functions which generates sudoku squares (creates random numbers for them that don't exist in their row and column).

The problem is that calling that function from `useEffect()` and consoling out sudoku squares generated, it generates 2 arrays of squares instead of one. If I run these functions in plain JS instead of react, everything works as expected and 81 square is generated.

What am I missing? Thanks!

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Square from './Square';

function App() {

    type SquareType = {
        id: number;
        digit: number;
        index: number;
        shown: boolean;
    }

    let row: Array<SquareType> = [];
    let previuosRows: Array<SquareType> = [];
    let sudoku: Array<SquareType> = [];
    const possibleOptionsForDigit = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    function generateRandomArrayIndex(unusedDigits: Array<number> ) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * unusedDigits.length);
    }

    function unusedDigitInRowAndColumn( sudoku: Array<SquareType>, row: Array<SquareType>, columnIndex: number ) {
        let digitsExistingInRow: Array<number> = [];
        let digitsExistingInColumn: Array<number> = [];
        let unusedDigitsInRow: Array<number> = [];
        let unusedDigitsInColumn: Array<number> = [];
        let unusedDigits: Array<number>;
        let randomDigitFromUnused: number;
        
        digitsExistingInRow = row.map(square => square.digit);
        unusedDigitsInRow = possibleOptionsForDigit.filter(digit => !digitsExistingInRow.includes(digit));
    
        digitsExistingInColumn = sudoku.filter(square => square.index === columnIndex).map(square => square.digit);
        unusedDigitsInColumn = possibleOptionsForDigit.filter(digit => !digitsExistingInColumn.includes(digit));
    
        unusedDigits = unusedDigitsInRow.filter(digit => unusedDigitsInColumn.includes(digit)); 
        randomDigitFromUnused = unusedDigits[generateRandomArrayIndex(unusedDigits)];
    
        return randomDigitFromUnused;
    }

    function createSudokValues() {
        let idIncremented: number = 0;
        let generatedUnusedDigit: number = 0;
        for ( let y = 1; y <= 9; y++ ) {
            for ( let columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 9; columnIndex++ ) {
                while (row.length <= 9) {
                    generatedUnusedDigit = unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(sudoku, row, columnIndex);
                    //console.log("unusedDigitInRowAndColumn ", unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(sudoku, row, columnIndex));
                    row.push(
                        {
                            id: idIncremented,
                            digit: generatedUnusedDigit,
                            index: columnIndex,
                            shown: true
                        }
                    );
                    idIncremented++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            previuosRows = [ ...sudoku];
            sudoku = [ ...previuosRows, ...row ];
            row = [];
        }
        return sudoku;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(createSudokValues())
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, []);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="pageContainer">
                <p>
                    Sudoku
                </p>
                <div className="sudokuContainer">
                    {
                        createSudokValues().map((square, idx) =>
                        <Square key={idx}></Square>
                        )
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

These are square objects printed out to the console (arrays with items [0 - 99] and [100 - 161] are generated although only [0 - 99] should be generated):

[image]

Comment: Not sure but you call the function twice (console.log and in your jsx) and you modify the mutable variable `row` at each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mcanzerini right, in `useEffect` you can calling `createSudokValues` and in jsx render `sudoku` without calling second time `createSudokValues`. You must use hook `useState` for `sudoku` to rerender the state in JSX while updating it. Then just do `sudoku.map()` instead of `createSudokValues().map()`. Example:

```
const [sudoku, setSudoku] = useState([]);


function createSudokValues() {
        let idIncremented: number = 0;
        let generatedUnusedDigit: number = 0;
        for ( let y = 1; y <= 9; y++ ) {
            for ( let columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= 9; columnIndex++ ) {
                while (row.length <= 9) {
                    generatedUnusedDigit = unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(sudoku, row, columnIndex);
                    //console.log("unusedDigitInRowAndColumn ", unusedDigitInRowAndColumn(sudoku, row, columnIndex));
                    row.push(
                    {
                        id: idIncremented,
                        digit: generatedUnusedDigit,
                        index: columnIndex,
                        shown: true
                    }
                );

                    idIncremented++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            setSudoku(prev => { 
               return [ ...prev, ...row]
            });
            row = [];
        }
}

useEffect(() => {
    createSudokValues();
}, []);
```

JSX:

```
{
    sudoku.map((square, idx) =>
        <Square key={idx}></Square>
    )
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for explaining that and providing me the solution! It let me understand which direction should I take. I had to add a TS type to sudoku state like so `const [sudoku, setSudoku] = useState<SquareType[]>([])` though and now only 1 like of sudoku is filled (1 inner loop)

Answer (score 1):

One obvious explanation is that Chrome console breaks an array of length > 100 into multiple parts,i.e., if the array is of length 210, console will log something like this:

```
> [0-99] 
> [100-199]
> [200-209]
length: 210
```

So if the array is of length 162, it will display them as the way you're getting.

**or**

If you're expecting 100 values,

This may be happening because of the empty dependency list in the useEffect hook.
Try passing a constant value to it.

For eg:

```js
useEffect(callback, [null]);
```

```js
useEffect(callback, [1]);
```